# Rate of convergence for sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I'm working on the following problem and I'm stuck.

[image]

My plan was to use SLLN, but this gives me an expression for $\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_{i}^p/n$ and it's not clear how to convert it to having denominator $n^{1/p}$. I'm wondering if maybe something involving borel cantelli is useful?

[source: Feb 1, 2012](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Post_2012_papers/Probability_2012-.pdf)

Comment: See Durrett *Probability Theory and Examples*, 2.5.1 and 2.5.2.